# past perfect for an event which takes place after the past simple

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

> I wanted to order something on the internet. I had asked for a new password when I realised that I had lost it. But I haven't yet received the new password.

first action the decision to order something
second action the forgetting of the password
third action  the asking of a new one
fourth action the wait

Why not "asked" past simple.  First you realised than you had lost then you asked for a new one. What I propose is

> I wanted to order something on the internet. I asked for a new password when I realised that I had lost it. But I haven't yet received the new password.

Comment: It's not clear here exactly what the sequence of events is, what you are 'reporting', what is supplemental, and what you are proposing instead. Could  you please edit your question to make this clearer?

Comment: The situation the OP describes is confusing, a passive is probably needed: "**I had been asked to enter my password**  *when I realized I had forgotten it. Although I  asked for a new one, it has not arrived.yet.*"

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to use the past perfect here.  You are correct that "asked" is the correct way to write this in your example.  You are basically saying, "When I realized that I had lost it, I asked for a new password."  It would only be correct to use the past perfect if you are indicating that something had been asked before another event took place, which does not make sense in this context.